# Error 80070002: The system can not find the file specified

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I have two scripts one that is run as a scheduled task and then calls another script.

This works normally, i.e manually running it but I when I run it from scheduled task it can't find the path.

[image]

Part 1 snippet

```
Dim objShell
str1= "hidden\part2.vbs"
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run str1

Set objShell = Nothing
```

This works normally, i.e. it can find part2.vbs but using scheduled task it does not work.

I am trying to make an install script that will run at startup.

This doesn't work even if the file is in the same folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the current working directory is correctly set or use an absolute path.

Comment: That worked, was pretty sure I already tried that but it's good to clarify :)